# PDFBox performance when loading PDDocument into memory from file for different user requests?

Tags: java, spring, pdfbox

On my Spring Web Server, I want to conditionally concatenate a single page to the beginning of a PDF document if a user has certain permissions.

The single page concatenated to the beginning will be a single-page PDF that only contains a simple page-turn graphic.

I've looked into PDFBox as a potential solution, though in the FAQ of PDFBox found [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html), it says the following:

> PDFBox has experimental support for read-only operations on the same PDDocument from different threads.
>   For all other uses cases only one thread may access a single document at a time. You can have multiple threads each accessing their own PDDocument object.

Since I can't use a single PDDocument instance in memory for all of my threads, would it be performant enough to load the same file on disk into a PDDocument instance and close that file on each user request that could occur?  If there is only one file on disk to load into a PDDocument instance in memory, and one PDDocument instance is required per thread, would response times of greater than 10 seconds occur when multiple users are hitting the same endpoint?

Comment: Use some form of memory caching with weak references. I think there are more than plenty implementations available already. Additionally remove references when the session invalidates.

Comment: You say your prefix document is *a single-page PDF that only contains a simple page-turn graphic* while you don't describe the main document that single page is added to. Obviously, though, both documents will play a role. It sounds like your prefix document won't be a problem resulting in long response times but the main document may.

Comment: @mkl - Thanks for the input.  I think that you make a good point, since the document that the single page is being concatenated to is at least 10 pages long.  My server currently just outputs the bytes that it gets from a database instance, but if I include the usage of PDFBox, I will have to marshall those bytes into a PDDocument instance and use them.  This would increase the response time too.

Comment: Indeed. Have you any information on the PDFs in question? E.g. their average and maximum sizes? And complexities?

Comment: I looked at the actual PDFs in question.  It turns out, the PDF is different for each user and has to be grabbed from a database, but each PDF is only one page long.  The PDF is also just a letter with a masthead, so it's not overly complicated.